# Enviar UTC de DateTime Javascript para C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, serialização

Tenho um projeto ASP.Net MVC da seguinte forma:

Em minha *view* tenho uma variável em JavaScript que guarda uma data:

```
var hoje = new Date();
```

Em meu *controller* tenho uma *action* que recebe via AJAX o valor da variável em JavaScript em uma variável C# do tipo `DateTime`.

```
public ActionResult ObterData(DateTime hoje)
{
   ...
   var utc = // Gostaria de obter o utc (Fuso Horário) da variável hoje como veio da View.
   ...
}
```

Comment: Você quer a hora em UTC ou você quer saber qual é o `TimeZone` dela?

Comment: Quero saber o TimeZone dela, UTC não tem relação com isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTC é o horário padrão universal, o chamado GMT, é a hora zero, a hora que independe do local onde está.

Esta informação do fuso horário não está disponível no tipo `DateTime`, portanto não pode ser obtida. Acho que fica pior vindo do cliente.

Em geral você deve tratar a data como UTC. Eventualmente você pode converter para a hora local. Se guardar como hora local (isto é possível com [`DateTimeKind`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0)), pode achar a diferença para o UTC. Talvez essa diferença te sirva para alguma coisa mas não diz que fuso horário é.

A única forma é ter uma informação adicional que guarde isto. Pode ser separado ou criar um novo tipo que encapsule a hora e o fuso horário. Se o código JavaScript não obter a informação do horário local (e claro que isto não é algo que você possa confiar) e não mandar para o servidor, não tem solução, a não ser que considere que a hora do servidor seja igual do cliente, mas é uma presunção que pode estar errada. Tem que mandar a diferença de horas do horário local para o horário GMT (UTC). Com esta informação adicional é possível fazer cálculos em cima do horário local do cliente.

Pode inclusive usar uma biblioteca como a [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) que tenha um tipo mais sofisticado. Mas a informação vindo do cliente precisa ser compatível.

Comment: Bem, o objetivo de forma resumida é que ao ser enviada uma data de um cliente que esteja rodando a aplicação no Meridiano de Greenwich eu consiga obter no `Controller` o seguinte `valor = 0:00`, mas caso o cliente esteja em Brasília `valor = -03:00`. Como esse valor seria chamado em termos técnicos? O objetivo é justamente fazer conversões depois com esses valores.

Comment: Primeiro, você sabe que não pode confiar nesta informação, certo? Você não tem controle sobre o que vem do cliente. Você não pode sequer garantir que venha uma informação se a hora é UTC ou Local e isto é o mínimo que você precisa ter para fazer qualquer cálculo neste sentido. Claro que qualquer dado pode vir errado. Mas não tem outra forma a não ser você pegar o fuso horário no cliente, com JS, guardar em algum campo que será enviado para o *controller* junto com a data. Não dá para receber só a data. Então esse `-03:00` tem que ser mandado pelo cliente de alguma forma.

Comment: No lado client, pode-se usar `getTimezoneOffset()` para determinar a diferença entre o horário local e UTC: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`